# How to prove that the system is locally stable using Lyapunov function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

3 equilibrium points are obtained in this system
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=y+1.6xy-2.7x\\
\dot{y}&=0.625x-xy+1.2y^2-0.7y
\end{align}
$$
[as in this streamplot graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hnbr.png)

(0,0) in blue

(0.3,0.5) is an unstable saddle point (in black)

(1.5,1.2) at the stable point (in red)

Calculating the Jacobian of the system gives
\begin{equation}
J = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
-2.7 + 1.6 y  &  1 +1.6 x \\ 
0.625 - y    & - 0.7 - x +2.4 y
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
with
2 stable points: 1 at the origin and another at the red point (as in the graph attached)

The eigenvalues of the system yields
$$
\lambda_{1,2}=\lambda+(\mbox{tr})\lambda+\mbox{det}
$$
where
$$\mbox{tr} = -3.4-x+4y \quad \mbox{and} \quad \mbox{det} = 1.265-4.9x+3.84x^2$$

I want to show that the system is locally stable at the red point, which I believe one of the method is by using Lyapunov function.

This is my first attempt so far (but this is when I assumed that the function is globally stable)

$$
\begin{align}
V(x,y)&=x^2-1.6y^2 \\
\dot{V} &= 2x\dot{x} -3.2y\dot{y} \\
&=1.6x^2y-5.4x^2+3.6xy^2-3.84y^3+2.24y^2
\end{align}
$$
which is not always positive definite (in $V$) and negative definite (in $\dot{V}$)

I’m still new with this approach, can anyone help to clarify the process? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you compute the Jacobian, and the linearization is stable, it is sufficient to conclude the local stability of the equilibrium. What is the goal to proceed with the Lyapunov function?

Comment: @Arastas Ok, I wasn’t aware that once it’s proven by linearisation, I don’t need to proceed with Lyapunov function. I was initially want to use this 2 dimensional system as an exercise to investigate the Lyapunov and proceed with three dimensional system next.

Comment: I agree with what Arastas said. But I would like to add that if you do want to go the Lyapunov function route then one has to at least pick a positive definite candidate Lyapunov function, however yours isn't. Picking a good Lyapunov function, such that $\dot{V}$ is (at least locally) negative definite, is difficult in general. So if one doesn't have to find one in order to show some stability result I would try to avoid it.